# safeAreaLayoutGuide guide not working from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

As suggested by some experts like @DonMag , i design the view in a separate controller, while trying to do so , every thing works, but when i use a navigation controller and there is a navigation bar at top, if i try and design in separate controller and then add its view to another controller the safeAreaLayoutGuide does not work and the view is attached to top of screen ignoring the safearea

SOLUTION as per @Mohammad Azam, DonMag solutions works as well , thanks

```
import UIKit

class NotesDesign: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
  
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func commonInit(){
               let notesTitle = UITextField()
               let notesContent = UITextView()
               
               
               let font = UIFont(name: "CourierNewPS-ItalicMT", size: 20)
               let fontM = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
               notesTitle.font = fontM.scaledFont(for: font!)
               
               notesContent.font = fontM.scaledFont(for: font!)
               
               
               notesTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant:250).isActive = true
               notesTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
               notesTitle.borderStyle = .line
               notesContent.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant:250).isActive = true
               notesContent.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
               notesContent.layer.borderWidth = 1
               let notesStack = UIStackView()
               notesStack.axis = .vertical
               notesStack.spacing = 20
               notesStack.alignment = .top
               notesStack.distribution = .fill
               
               
               notesStack.addArrangedSubview(notesTitle)
               notesStack.addArrangedSubview(notesContent)
               // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
               
               notesStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               addSubview(notesStack)
              
               notesStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
               notesStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
               notesStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
               notesStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
          
           
           
    }
    
}
```

And where i call it

```
import UIKit

class AddNotesViewController: UIViewController {
   var design = NotesDesign()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(design)
        design.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveData))
    }
    

    @objc func saveData() {
        
    }

}
```

And this is what i get

[image]

Comment: Check warnings in Xcode for conflicting constraints as you are setting `notesStack.topAnchor` twice one with `safeAreaLayoutGuide` and one with `view.topAnchor`

Comment: @MohammadAzam - sorry for this, the later one is commented out in my xcode some how i uncommented it while copying, there are no warnings i get

Comment: if you want to design view separately then subclass `UIView` class and design..You are implementing a `UIViewController` and taking its view..it seems inappropriate.

Comment: @MohammadAzam - your suggestion acted upon and now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking a view from its ViewController and adding it as a subview to another view, you need to constrain it just like you would with any other added subview:

```
class AddNotesViewController: UIViewController {
    var design = NotesViewDesign()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(design.view)

        // a view loaded from a UIViewController has .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        design.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain the loaded view
            design.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            design.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            design.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            design.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveData))
    }
    
    
    @objc func saveData() {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This solution works well, also Mohammad Azam solution worked, i updated my question with working code, thanks